# Requested url not found on server error

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, web, web-deployment

I made a website which I am temporarily hosting in app engine. I am able to navigate through the pages when I open the HTML files on my computer. It only fails when I head to http://www.alshafarconstruction.appspot.com/index.html.

**Error Message:**

```
Error: Not Found

The requested URL /contact.html was not found on this server
```

**app.yaml:**

```
application: alshafarnew
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|swf|xml))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css|swf|xml))

- url: /(.*\.html)
  static_files: \1
  upload: index.html

- url: /.*
  script: main.py
```

**main.py:**

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

class IndexHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        if self.request.url.endswith('/'):
            path = '%sindex.html'%self.request.url

        self.redirect(path)

    def post(self):
        self.get()

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/.*', IndexHandler)], debug=True)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I've checked the dashboard and find that the HTML files are there. I am new to website deployment and design. Can anyone suggest possible errors? I have already visited many sites for a solution.

Comment: In the dashboard, is there a preview link for the `contact.html` page? if you click on it, what `URL` do you get?

Comment: might be an idea to paste your app.yaml in as that manages routing etc.

Comment: @PaulCollingwood had posted it aslso as an updation to my question

Comment: @NickR Iam able to open the dashboard but can you pls advice where I can get the details

Comment: something you are missing. In your app.yaml your handlers should have been handling any page to the index.html . Did you upload the app?

Comment: @JimmyKane Thanks  I had uploaded it I had provided the URl also

Comment: use `static_files: index.html` instead of `static_files: \1`

Comment: @nizz I added the static_files: index.html but I am now getting only the index page and nop link pages

Comment: @sreenathsreenath I though you wanted a sample static site that every link would render the index page. Well, I see that you've already been given the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Static_file_pattern_handlers) hints that static and application files are uploaded separately, so while the files may be there, it might be that they're being uploaded in the application-files part.

You currently have an `upload` directive telling it to only upload `index.html`:

```
- url: /(.*\.html)
  static_files: \1
  upload: index.html
```

<sup>(actually, it's a regular expression, so it would also upload, for example `index@html` if it existed)</sup>
This suggests that you might want to make that regular expression match all HTML files:

```
- url: /(.*\.html)
  static_files: \1
  upload: .*\.html
```

Comment: do you mean I have to change the App file with the code you had given below

Comment: @sreenathsreenath: Yes; you'll need to change `app.yaml` so that the part corresponding to HTML files has an `upload` property of `.*\.html`.

Comment: Thank you you saved me from the hell ..it works now thank you bro